# Cannot Use Python 2 from Command Line

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.5, python-3.6

I recently tried to uninstall Python 3.5.2 and installed Python 3.6.0. I used to use `python` in the command line to run Python 3.5.2 from the command line, and `py` to run Python 2.7.12. Now, `python` runs Python 3.5.2, and `py` runs Python 3.6.0. I am running Windows 10, and `python3`, `python2`, `py2`, and `py3` do not do anything.

Comment: why don't you reinstall python 2.7.12 ?

Comment: In the new launcher that's distributed with 3.6, running py.exe on the command line now runs the highest version of Python 3.x that's installed. To run Python 2 instead, use `py -2`. To make this the default, set the environment variable `PY_PYTHON=2`.

Comment: using a package manager like Anaconda can simplify the process of switching versions or using multiple versions on your computer. you can read more [HERE](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't bother adding Python to the path.  Just use:

```
py            Run highest version of Python (override with PY_PTYHON environment variable).
py -2         Run highest version of Python 2.
py -3         Run highest verssion of Python 3.
py -2.7       Run Python 2.7.
py -2.7-32    Run python 2.7 32-bit when on a 64-bit system.
```

More: https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows

Note you can also specify in scripts which version to use as well with, for example:

```
#!python2
#!python3
#!python2.7
```

Comment: Note that if you're using the old, pre-3.6 version of the launcher, it defaults to running the highest version of Python 2, if installed, and otherwise the highest version of Python 3. This was changed in 3.6 to prefer Python 3. However, for virtual shebangs in scripts, such as `#!python` and `#!/usr/bin/python`, the new version of the launcher still maps "python" to Python 2 for the sake of Unix compatibility.